# Questions about cyclic group which is generated by integer mod n.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In [Integer and modular addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Integer_and_modular_addition) of Cyclic group:

> For every positive integer n, the set of integers modulo n, again with
>   the operation of addition, forms a finite cyclic group, the group
>   Z/n. An element g is a generator of this group if g is relatively
>   prime to n. Thus, the number of different generators is φ(n), where φ
>   is the Euler totient function, the function that counts the number of
>   numbers modulo n that are relatively prime to n. Every finite cyclic
>   group is isomorphic to a group Z/n, where n is the order of the group.

I have following doubts about the above statements:
(1)

> For every positive integer n, the set of integers modulo n, again with
>   the operation of addition, forms a finite cyclic group, the group
>   Z/n.

I am not a nitpicker, but think it should be "`again with the operation of addition modulo n`", right?

(2)

> An element g is a generator of this group if g is relatively prime to n.

How can prove the the `g` and `n` must be coprime?

Comment: Your "nitpick" is correct.

Comment: If $g,n$ are not coprime, you can't generate $1$. Suppose $g,n$ have a common factor, $d$ say, where $d > 1$. Then any multiple of $g$ will be a multiple of $d$, and will still be a multiple of $d$ after you mod out by $n$, so you can't get $1$.

Comment: @quasi Thanks for your comments? Forgive my greedy requirement, how can manifest if g and n are coprime, the g must be the generator?

Comment: Suppose $g,n$ are coprime. Show that no two of the $n$ numbers
$$0,g,2g,...,(n-1)g$$
are congruent mod $n$, hence they are still pairwise non-congruent when modded out by $n$. But then g generates all $n$ elements of $Z_n$.

Comment: “`two of the n numbers are congruent mod n`”? If I understand right, the n numbers mod `n` should generate 0, 1, ... n-1. Right? Thanks!

Comment: "_no_ two of the numbers ..."

Comment: Since the $n$ generated numbers are distinct, and since $Z_n$ only has $n$ elements, the generated numbers must comprise all of $Z_n$, but not in the same order (unless the generator is $1$).

Answer (score 1):

One way to see it is that if $\lvert g\rvert =n$, then $\lvert g^k\rvert =n/(n,k)$.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4484127/1070376) I gave a proof.

Answer (score -1):

Given any number $u \in \Bbb Z$. Saying that $g$ is a generator$\mod n$ is equivalent to say $\exists x, y \in \Bbb Z: u = xg+yn$. But if $g$ and  $n$ share a factor $d$ so does $u$, so values of $u$ which are not multiples of $d$ can't be reached.

Answer (score -1):

Number (2) is a consequence of the [*Bézout Identity*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), which states that any linear combination of two integers is a multiple of the greatest common divisors of those integers, as Marc has already stated. In particular, there exists a linear combination of them that is equal to the GCD

Thus given two integers $g$ and $n$, coprimes, there exists a linear combination $xg + yn$ such that $xg + yn = \gcd(g,n) = 1$.

This means that $xy + gn \equiv 1 (\text{mod } n)$. Reorganizing, we obtain

$$
    xy \equiv 1 + (-y)n \equiv 1 (\text{mod } n)
$$

An element $k \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ can then be written $kxg$, which is a multiple of $g$. So $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

As to (1), as others have pointed out, you're correct.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to prove:

Say g is a generator, then if you increase g by k times is a k*g. We know that i and (i+i*n)%n are same. So increasing it by n/gcd(g, n) yields the same.

Also the order of such generator should be n/gcd(n, g). So if it has to become a generator it has to have n/gcd(n, g) be equal to n. That means gcd(n, g)=1 => n and g are coprime.

Comment: Is my proof wrong? Please let me know the mistake in my proof if you have downvoted my answer.